# Redshift SQL: How to get values from each group into a function without referring to groups by name?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query in redshift sql that builds a table like this:

```
|  groupname |  value | 
:------------:--------|
|  control   |   10   |
|  variant   |   11   |
```

Now I need to pass the values for each group into a UDF that I would normally use like this:

```
with inputs_ as (
  select 
     10  as control_value,
     11 as variant_value
 )
select some_function(
   control_value,
   variant_value) as result, * from inputs_
```

Is there a way to write some SQL that would grab the values by groupname and pass them into the function, without referring to the groupname by name (because names like "control" and "variant" can change)?  If this was a pandas dataframe I'd do it by iterating over rows, but it has to be SQL.

Comment: How else do you refer to them, if not by name?

Comment: By row numbers, because the names can change

Comment: There are no such things as "row numbers" in SQL unless a column stores that information.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.